# How to adjust the data in grid columns in placing the data dynamically from the backend

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

I want to place the maps in grid system from the backend I have placed the maps but coming in vertical way.

But My requirement is based on the data (i.e  no of maps) it has to adjust the grids

*for ex.* if the maps are two it has to show two maps one by one, if it has 4 it has to show two maps in first row and two maps in second row  and so on in bootstrap grid system.

**.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let x of data ; let i =index">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
       
        <div id="x{{i}}"  ng-onload="mulmaps(x{{i}});" style="height: 300px;"></div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By not using `.container`, `.row` or `.col` in your loop, but use a [card layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/#card-layout) like `.card-deck`.

Since `.card-deck` is a flex container, the width of the children is now under your control with flex-grow, -shrink and -basis.

```
<div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card">...</div>
    <!-- ... repeat n times depending on your data -->
</div>
```

With CSS media queries you can cover the width of the cards even more simply by changing flex-basis.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/mze71o3y/)**

Comment: Thanks@ Tim Vermaelen ,but I want to show the map in a row  based on the odd and even number of columns(maps) from  the backend .If the maps(columns are 1 show single row, if the columns are two show the two maps in the row if the columns are three place two maps in first row and third map in second row.I have stucked  here can you please help for my requirement.

Comment: In almost all cases where I had to do something like that, I used a modulus operator => iteratorIndex % 2 === 0 ? startRow startCol else startCol. Repeat the modulus to endRow.

Comment: I did not get you, can you please edit the above code so that I can use that.

Comment: How can I place startRow  startCol

Comment: Something like this I mean: https://snook.ca/archives/php/the_modulo_oper.
Maybe you can still get away with card-deck and use nth selector in CSS \o/